# How many templates can be applied to a summoned creature(s)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoning, character-templates

How many templates can be applied to a summoned creature?

For instance the [summon monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) spell automatically comes with celestial or fiendish.

Say I was to use a [rod of giant summoning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-giant-summoning) with it which grants the giant template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There is no limit.

Some creatures on [the summon monster list](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) will also have a template applied, such as giant or dire creatures. Even [multiple templates](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/skeleton-medium/skeleton-bloody) before you even apply anything.

A few examples are:

1. Young frost giant
2. [Dire Shark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/shark/dire-shark)
3. [Dire Crocodile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/crocodilians/crocodile/dire-crocodile)
4. Human natural wererat rogue 2

So if you have anything that allows you to apply a template on the summoned creature, such as [Skeleton Summons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/skeleton-summoner) or [Summon Good Monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/summon-good-monster), that template is applied on top of whatever template the creature already has.

> For instance the summon monster spell automatically comes with celestial or fiendish.

Only those marked with an "*", which are mostly animals.